# How to set width in percentage of splitLayoutPanel elements.?

Tags: gwt

How can I give a width in percentage of west element. I have a given size as "60" and also selected unit as PCT but it is not working.

```
                    <g:SplitLayoutPanel>
                        <g:west size="60" unit="PCT">
                            <g:HorizontalPanel>
                                .......
                            </g:HorizontalPanel>
                        </g:west>
                    </g:SplitLayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

SplitLayoutPanel only supports PX unit sizes ([see documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SplitLayoutPanel.html)).

If percentage sizing is a must and you can't use anything but SplitLayoutPanel for your task, you could calculate and set pixel sizes of your sub-panels programmatically, perhaps by extending the panel and overriding the panel's [onResize()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RequiresResize.html#onResize%28%29).

Comment: Yes, Boris Brudnoy. we can specify only width in px to SplitLayout. But is there any way to give it per. Like <g:east size="200" unit="EM"> or <g:east size="60" unit="PCT"> or <g:east size="400" unit="px"> or otherway

Comment: AFAIK you're unable to override units for sub-panels. I expanded the answer as well.